# std::async in clang 3.0 + libc++ doesn't work?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, clang, libc++

I just compiled and installed clang+llvm 3.0 on my ubuntu 10.04, and also libc++ from svn. As the status in libc++ shows thread support is complete, I wanted to try std::async. So I follow the example given by Anthony Williams in

http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/multithreading-in-c++0x-part-8-futures-and-promises.html

And just make minor change to make it compile:

```
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

int calculate_the_answer_to_LtUaE()
{
  return 42;
}

void do_stuff()
{
  std::cout << "doing stuff" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  std::future<int> the_answer=std::async(calculate_the_answer_to_LtUaE);
  do_stuff();
  std::cout<<"The answer to life, the universe and everything is "
    <<the_answer.get()<<std::endl;
}
```

And I compile with

clang++ --std=c++0x -stdlib=libc++ -lpthread async.cpp

However, it runs and always finish with a core dump:

doing stuff 
The answer to life, the universe and everything is Aborted (core dumped)

I check the core dump and it shows stack like this (which I don't quite get a hint)

```
#0  0x00007fd0a1a7ba75 in raise () from /lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007fd0a1a7f5c0 in abort () from /lib/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007fd0a22a735b in std::exception_ptr::~exception_ptr (this=) at ../src/exception.cpp:130
#3  0x0000000000404178 in void std::__1::__assoc_state::set_value(int&&) ()
#4  0x00000000004051ae in _ZNSt3__119__async_assoc_stateIiNS_12__async_funcIPFivEJEEEE9__executeEv ()
#5  0x0000000000404e00 in _ZNSt3__114__thread_proxyINS_5tupleIJMNS_19__async_assoc_stateIiNS_12__async_funcIPFivEJEEEEEFvvEPS7_EEEEEPvSC_ ()
#6  0x00007fd0a250f9ca in start_thread () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
#7  0x00007fd0a1b2e70d in clone () from /lib/libc.so.6
#8  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Anybody has an idea why?

Comment: An abort means that an assertion has failed. Look at assert()s in exception.cpp near line 130. Use of gdb to break on abort and analyze the locals is strongly recommended.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ran your example on OS X Lion, using:

```
clang++ -std=c++0x -stdlib=libc++ async.cpp
```

And the program output:

```
doing stuff
The answer to life, the universe and everything is 42
```

Inspecting the source of libc++ as suggested by moshbear's comment I see:

```
exception_ptr::~exception_ptr() _NOEXCEPT
{
#if HAVE_DEPENDENT_EH_ABI
    __cxa_decrement_exception_refcount(__ptr_);
#else
    #warning exception_ptr not yet implemented
    ::abort();
#endif  // __APPLE__
}
```

It appears to me that `~exception_ptr()` has not been ported to ubuntu 10.04.  This is a low-level facility not implementable in portable C++.  Work on creating a GPL-free implementation of this level is ongoing at [libc++abi](http://libcxxabi.llvm.org/).  I can assure you that libc++abi is not ready for prime time at this time.

There has also been an independent effort at this low-level library at:  https://github.com/pathscale/libcxxrt .  I do not know the status of this library nor whether it has been ported to ubuntu.